# Find a list of patterns in a list of string in python

Tags: python, string, list, pattern-matching

given the list of strings

```
strings = ['abc123', 'bd45', 'ef1234']
```

how can I test if any of these patterns match (all or partially) any of the above strings?

```
patterns = ['ab','nee', 'yeah']
```

The above should return True.

For example, all these patterns should return true:

```
patterns1 = ['ab','nee', 'yeah']
patterns2 = ['ab', '123']
patterns3 = ['ab','b', '123']
```

while these should return False:

```
patterns4 = ['abn','nee', 'yeah']
patterns5 = ['n', 'yes']
```

Comment: do they need to be exact matches? Or can they match a substring?

Comment: You need to describe more clearly what you mean - give some example output too. Show us what you tried and explain what the problem is with it.

Comment: If you show your desired output from the above input, it would help remove ambiguity about what you are asking for and, in particular, what "matches" mean to you.

Comment: Thanks, I have expanded the question description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by perfoming a python list comprehension

```
any([ p in s for p in patterns for s in strings ])
```

Comment: why the downvotes? this looks right to me... although I think you want to switch the order of the `for blah in blahblah` oh cause he is the OP ... I see what you did there ... still its not against the rules

Comment: You are right the order can be switched, while producing the same output.

Comment: they both work fine ... I guess its a case of which you expect more of strings or patters .... http://ideone.com/5EKqsJ should explain the difference ... while subtle I think it makes more sense to use the second verions

Comment: This isn't a [nested list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions).

Comment: That's not what nested means in the context of list comprehensions. Did you read the link?

Comment: I see that chaining two 'for .. in ..' is not the same as nested list comprehensions. I have edited the answer about it.